# SSD for Linux system with Linux virtual machines

Tags: linux, ssd, virtual-machines

I want to buy an SSD for the specified reasons, and reliability and price are the most important for me. I want to do/learn C++ programming and get to know Linux in a deeper level. My budget would be 155 USD at most.

Comment: So, what are the specified reasons?  You don't really specify.  Pretty vague.

Comment: See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/289040/119271) Basically, any SSD will do, but stick to name brands like [Kingston](http://amzn.to/2hSGvZf)

Comment: The [Crucial BX300](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073W4N5KB/) is really cheap right now for some reason. It's a mid range instead of entry level SSD, meaning it has MLC and the like. I'm still a little paranoid about Kingston SSDs because of a [switcheroo](https://www.anandtech.com/show/7763/an-update-to-kingston-ssdnow-v300-a-switch-to-slower-micron-nand) they did a while back.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Alpha3031, but right now this SSD can't be purchased in my country. It does seem a great deal though, so I will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main uses would be

- Linux OS
- Programming (C++)
- Virtual machines

while your requirements are

- reliability
- price

Assuming you want an internal SSD,

I would say that you would in theory want an SSD with [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell#Single-level_cell), however, they are more expensive.

For example a search on newegg.com for SLC in the range $100-200 resulted in 1 match

- [WD Green M.2 2280 240GB Internal SSD ($147.96)](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAD7H5JF6834)
- disclaimer I do not use newegg but that was the only international product comparison search I knew that has "power search".

In practice, given your intended use, a [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell#Multi-level_cell) based SSD should suffice. A search for MLC in the same range resulted in numerous products. The linked Wikipedia article even states that

> In February 2016, a study was published that showed little difference in practice between the reliability of SLC and MLC.

(referencing Bianca Schroeder and Arif Merchant (February 22, 2016). "Flash Reliability in Production: The Expected and the Unexpected". Conference on File and Storage Technologies. Usenix. Retrieved November 3, 2016.)

You also need to ensure that the SSD you purchase support

> ... the ATA_TRIM command for sustained long-term performance and wear-leveling.

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives.

The only thing that I am aware of when using SSD with Linux is to ensure that the file system you use for the SSD supports TRIM. See the referenced [archlinux link on SSD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives).

Given your intended use I would say any SSD with SATA revision 3.0 ("SATA 3" or "SATA III") interface should perform well enough.

> You could say the maximum for SATA revision 3.0 is 6Gb/s, and that the maximum for SATA revision 3.2 is 16Gb/s.

- https://superuser.com/questions/807226/sata-3-theoretical-speed

I personally run an external SSD with USB 3.0 (can transfer data at up to 5 Gbit/s that is 625 MB/s according to Wikipedia) from where amongst other things I run virtual machines (Windows 7, Linux). For your stated uses I doubt you will have any performance issues.

If you want to narrow down your search (MLC) in an effort to improve performance then I would recommend considering an SSD with [NVMe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express) interface if your motherboard supports it. The same search on newegg adding "PCI-Express 3.0 x4" narrows the search down to about 20.

I recommend searching for reviews or comparison videos for more specific examples. My favorite is [NVMe SSD Review - Which Should You Buy? - 2017 Edition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqaZTwW_X2o&index=3&list=LLWZTE9hZO-zwSYsFBwqG2Rw). Notice what he says in the beginning of the review; NVMe is for high-end machines; for mid-range computer see his "SATA SSD" review.

Good luck!

**PS**

Reading Digital Boffon's comment I remembered that I forgot to mention something about read-write operations -- which would have basically been the same tl;dr as the answer Boffon referenced

> Yes, there's a limit, but you needn't worry about it. You simply won't be able to perform enough read/write operations before you run out of capacity.

My source however was *["The SSD Endurance Experiment: They're all dead
This is the end, beautiful friend" by Geoff Gasior — 10:22 AM on March 12, 2015](http://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead)*.